# Handlebars: inherited/implicit parameters

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there an easy way how to pass a "configuration" parameter to all embedded partials in handlebars?
In my case, I would like to set language by the page layout partial and would like all the embedded partials to have access to it, something like this:

`@layout-en.hbs`:

```
SOMEHOW SETTING LANG PARAMETER TO "EN"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
  <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Top of all English pages</p>
 {{{content}}}
 <p>Footer of all English pages</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`@layout-fr.hbs` - analogous

`some-page-en.hbs`:

```
{{#> @layout_en title="Title in English"}}

some content in English

{{#> demo}}

some more content in English

{{/@layout_en}}
```

`some-page-fr.hbs`:

```
{{#> @layout_fr title="Title in French"}}

some content in French

{{#> demo}}

some more content in French

{{/@layout_fr}}
```

Is it possible for `demo` to return a button with a different text when included on a page using `layout_en` and different when on a page using `layout_fr`?

Or should this be done completely differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set a variable that is accessible to all views and partials that are rendered in the response. I am doubtful that such a variable could be set from a partial and, even if it could, I would recommend against it because I think it would make the application more difficult to troubleshoot if global variables were being set in views.

Instead, I think a better approach would be to set such a variable in your controller logic.

You have not mentioned what Node web server framework you are using, but I am going to assume you are using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) with the [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) package.

The express API provides a [locals](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals) object on the response (`res`), to which variables can be attached and made available to all rendered templates.

A simple example of setting a global `lang` variable within our express handlers looks like:

```
app.get("/en", (req, res) => {
  res.locals.lang = "en";
  res.render("some-page-en");
});

app.get("/fr", (req, res) => {
  res.locals.lang = "fr";
  res.render("some-page-fr");
});
```

This will allow us to use `{{lang}}` from within any rendered view/layout/partial and the corresponding value will be rendered.

The problem with this approach is that it does allow for simple conditions within our template of the sort `lang === "fr" ? "French content" : "English content"`. This is because Handlebars does not ship with a way to perform such a conditional check. A [custom helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers) could help, however, if your application will only support the *two* languages - English and French - then we could replace our `lang` string variable with a boolean one - ex., `isFrench`:

```
app.get("/en", (req, res) => {
  res.locals.isFrench = false;
  res.render("some-page-en");
});

app.get("/fr", (req, res) => {
  res.locals.isFrench = true;
  res.render("some-page-fr");
});
```

As a boolean, this variable can be used with a [Handlebars `#if` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if). The `demo` partial could then look something like:

```
<button type="button">
  {{#if isFrench}}
    Cliquez ici
  {{else}}
    Click here
  {{/if}}
</button>
```

Additionally, I would recommend using a similar pattern within a single layout file instead of potentially having an English and a French layout with mostly duplicated HTML.

---

Additional note:

`{{#> demo}}` on its own is not valid Handlebars syntax. The `#>` is for rendering [Partial Blocks](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-blocks) and those must have an accompanying closing tag: `{{/demo}}`. A regular (non-Block) partial would be rendered with `{{> demo}}`.